# Какие типы вопросов существуют в русском языке?

Tags: обучение, методика, классификация

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как они подразделяются? И как объяснить это ребенку в 3 классе понятным языком?

Comment: Интересно, откуда этот "цветок" с редкостной чушью в лепестках, да ещё и с орфографической ошибкой? Не нужно этой ерундой пичкать ребенка.

Comment: Конечно, постановка вопроса некорректна, но это можно исправить, оформление тоже на любителя. В то же время это задание связано с развитием речи и мышления ребенка, учит его умению классифицировать текст.  Он может сам придумать примеры вопросов или определить вид заданного  вопроса. А если ребенок сообразительный, он может дополнить эту классификацию, а также понять,  что любой материал можно систематизировать и придумать собственную классификацию чего-нибудь. А вот некорректная постановка вопроса очень нежелательна.

Comment: Но при чем тут русский язык? Эти "виды вопросов" что, характерны только для русского языка? И потом: вы когда-нибудь видели такую, с позволения сказать, "классификацию"? Чушь – она и есть чушь.

Comment: @Niemand Вот этот цветочек ("ромашка Блума") вошёл в какие-то учебники и методички для учителей (см. гугл). Поэтому вполне естественно, что об этом спрашивают  пользователи форума. (Не знаю, кто поставил минус за вопрос, но это противоречит духу rus.se — мы должны выполнять задачу популяризации знаний, а не набивать себе цену унижая других.)

Comment: @Niemand Вопрос был исправлен при ответе, в нем речь идет даже не о классификации как таковой (можно придумать любую классификацию), а о семантической характеристике различных вопросов. К указанным видам можно добавить и другие. К примеру, мы говорим: иронический вопрос, риторический вопрос. Этот список можно, наверное, продолжить. Кстати, неплохое упражнение даже для взрослых пользователей.

Comment: @grizzly, мы можем популяризировать _знания_, а не чушь собачью. То, что это чушь, должно быть ясно любому приличному выпускнику средней школы. Да, а минус поставил я, как нетрудно понять.

Comment: @Jasmin, неплохое упражнение ДАЖЕ для взрослых? Стало быть, для третьеклассников тем паче? Семантическая характеристика?! Иронический вопрос, риторический вопрос -- в третьем классе?! Хотел бы посмотреть на автора этого цвЯточка...

Comment: Брошу свои пять копеек. Я не готов полностью. поддержать  Niemand'а d в его оценках самого приема, но однозначно, что к русскому языку это за уши притянуто. Никакой популяризацией русистики тут и не пахнет, скорее уж профанацией.

Comment: Присоединяюсь к @behemothus

Answer (score 2):

**Желательно задать (и отредактировать) вопрос  следующим образом** (ввиду его неоднозначного восприятия  участниками форума):

**Какие виды вопросов можно выделить в русском языке?**

В этом задании среди вопросов выделили 6 видов и дали им название. Как понятным языком объяснить это ребенку в 3 классе и какие можно привести примеры?

**ОТВЕТ**

Вопросы бывают разные.  Если вопрос связан только с получением информации, то такой вопрос можно назвать **простым,** так как у него нет дополнительной характеристики.

**Практические вопросы**  задаются в процессе работы (как что-то сделать). **Творческие вопросы** связаны с  фантазией, сочинительством, придумыванием  и обычно касаются литературы, театра, живописи. **Оценочные вопросы** задаются в том случае, если нужно узнать чьё-либо мнение (нравится или не нравится и почему). Если нужно что-то узнать подробнее, то задают **уточняющий вопрос**. И наконец, **вопрос-интерпретация** связан с пониманием. Такие вопросы задаются, если объясняется какая-то тема, но в ней что-то кажется непонятным.

**ПРИМЕРЫ**

1) **Творческий вопрос**: Как на сцене изобразить походку Бабы-Яги? Как нарисовать ветер?

2) **Практический вопрос**: Какие краски надо смешать, чтобы получить фиолетовый цвет?

3) **Оценочный вопрос**: Почему ты считаешь эту книгу интересной?

4) **Уточняющий вопрос**: Когда прилетают ласточки? ― Ласточки прилетают весной. ― А в каком именно месяце они прилетают?

5) **Простой вопрос**: Ты пойдешь сегодня на тренировку? ― Да, пойду.

6) **Вопрос-интерпретация:**

**ИНТЕРПРЕТАЦИЯ**  [лат. interpretatio ― разъяснение] Книжн. 1. Толкование, объяснение, разъяснение смысла, значения чего-л. 2. Творческое раскрытие образа или музыкального произведения исполнителем.

Если вопрос-интерпретация связан **с пониманием,** то можно представить такой диалог:

— Синонимы — это слова, звучание и написание которых различно, но при этом у них одинаковое или похожее значение, например: огонь — пламя, трудный — тяжелый. —  **А зачем нужны синонимы в том случае, когда у них одинаковое значение?** Ведь получается, что это лишние слова.

Comment: Вопрос "когда прилетают ласточки" к каким вопросам по этой классификации относится?

Comment: Я думаю, что к простым, так как другие варианты не подходят.

Comment: Вопрос-интерпретация - это видимо, что-то вроде, - "Дядя Петя, ты дурак?"

Comment: @МаркИз Я посмотрел первоисточники Б.Блума, по мотивам работы которого пытались делать эту "ромашку Блума" (там, правда, много, и я всё не читал). Вообще в его работе рассматривается таксономия тестовых заданий, а интерпретация находится в группе "понимание". Думаю, что под "вопросами-интерпретациями" понимаются "вопросы, относящиеся к умению интерпретировать информацию".

Comment: @Jasmin, а вы видели когда-нибудь подобную "классификацию"? Типы вопросов - это вот какие: вопросы к подлежащему, вопросы с отрицанием и.т.п. А это что?!

Answer (score 0):

Я готов согласиться с мнением, высказанном в комментариях. Вопрос совершенно некорректный для ресурса по русскому языку.

Во-первых, сама предлагаемая систематика весьма странная, ничего подобного ранее не встречал. Кто вообще её придумал - и почему она такая?
Во-вторых, судя по направленности, "вопросы" здесь понимаются не как грамматическое средство, а как некоторое подмножество когнитологии (науки о знаниях), типа чем вообще может интересоваться человек. Такие же вопросы можно задать хоть на японском, хоть на суахили...

Ну и грубая орфографическая ошибка тоже не прибавляет ощущения, что автор сам владеет русским.

> И как объяснить это ребенку в 3 классе понятным языком?

Ответ таков. Если это не из утвержденного школой учебника, то ребенку надо дать цветные фломастеры и предложить разрисовать этот цветочек. 
Ну а если это учительская инициатива, то забирать из такой школы как можно скорее.

PS Я очень поверхностно знаком с теориями Блума, но мне кажется, что представленное на этом цветочке даже на выхолощенную версию не тянет. Если это действительно "по мотивам" Блума, то тем более лучше держаться подальше. Но, повторюсь, в любом случае, это не к русскому языку относится, в лучшем случае - к теории коммуникации.

(++)
Вот нашел нечто.
https://infourok.ru/romashka-bluma-na-urokah-russkogo-yazika-i-literaturi-2377998.html
Обращает на себя внимание то, что даже тут прием обозначен как **направленный на развитие мышления**, а не русского языка. То есть для урока литературы (скорее даже зарубежной, чем русской) еще худо-бедно сойдет, но никак не для русского языка.

Comment: А что плохого в том, что на уроке русского языка дети будут развивать мышление, или это надо делать только на уроках физики и математики? Изучение смысла речи не  менее важно, чем изучение его формы, а у нас коммуникативности текста уделяется очень мало внимания, некоторые и слова-то такого не знают. Форма и содержание тесно связаны друг с другом, но при этом форма существует для содержания, а не наоборот. А как надо классифицировать вопросы:  от подлежащего к сказуемому и наоборот? Или еще: они бывают общие и частные. Это доступно и интересно детям, это их развивает?

Comment: @Jasmin  *Очень возможно, что Айседора Дункан так и делает. Может быть, она в кабинете обедает, а в ванной режет кроликов. Может быть. Но я — не Айседора Дункан. Я буду обедать в столовой, а оперировать в операционной! Передайте это общему собранию.* (С)

Comment: Мило, что Вы это вспомнили (я тоже люблю Булгакова) , но мне кажется, что это не совсем по теме. Зачем 11 лет изучать в школе грамматику и орфографию и при этом не уметь правильно говорить и грамотно писать. Ведь это умение касается людей всех профессий, а не только филологов. Язык - это прежде всего инструмент, его нужно не только "проходить", но и уметь им пользоваться. Нельзя изучать форму речи ОТДЕЛЬНО от содержания, а у нас обычно именно так  и делается.  А вот обедать, спать и работать надо  в ОТДЕЛЬНЫХ комнатах,  здесь Вы правы (если, конечно, есть такая возможность).

Comment: *и при этом не уметь правильно говорить и грамотно писать* - ві считаете, что гадание на ромашке Блума может научить детей правильно ***говорить***? Тогда пусть это прямо напишут адепты этого подхода. Пока что я во всех источниках вижу только пространные соображения насчет развития мыслительных способностей и прочего. А умение мыслить и  умение говорить - совсем не одно и тоже. Тем более, если говорить об умении говорить на одном каком-то языке. Так что, как ни крути, опять какая-то Айседора Дункан получается.